# на PHP на сервере перестал выполняться shell_exec

Tags: php, shell, svn, site

На сайте (на сервере) выполняется следующий php код (mysite/test.php):

```
    // получить информацию и последней ревизии проекта 
    $revisionData = shell_exec('svn info -r HEAD "https://mysite:8443/svn/mysite-repository/"');

    // извлечь данные из полученной информации
//  $res1 = preg_match('|^Revision: (\d+)$|mei',         $revisionData, $revisionLastVersion);
//  $res2 = preg_match('|^Last Changed Date: (.*)$|mei', $revisionData, $revisionLastTimeUpdate);

    // сформировать результат
    $projectInfo = array(
        'revisionLastVersion'     => (($res1 == 0) ? 0 : $revisionLastVersion[1]),
        'revisionLastTimeUpdate'  => (($res2 == 0) ? 0 : $revisionLastTimeUpdate[1]),
        'creation_time'           => date("Y-m-d H:i:s O (D, d M Y)"),
    );
```

который должен определить, когда последний раз я сохранял сайт в репозитории (svn).

Раньше все работало замечательно, но после перезагрузки админами сервера данный код перестал работать. Ошибки не выдаются никакие, просто как будто висит.

Когда на сервере пытаюсь выполнить команду `svn info -r HEAD "https://mysite:8443/svn/mysite-repository/"` на сервере локально через командную строку (с правами админа или нет - без разницы), то всё работает замечательно.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить эту же команду с правами пользователя вебсервера

Comment: а `shell_exec` вообще работает? Может админы поправили конфиг

Answer (score 1):

варианта 2 - права на исполнение или вообще запрет функции
скорее первое - особенно если через http запуск от веб-юзера.
спросите у админов - как так получилось

Answer (score 0):

обнаружилось следующее:

`shell_exec` нормальное выполняет бесправные команды, типа `schell_exec('echo TEST')` или `exec` выполняет .bat с такой же командой, но вот вызов `svn` напрочь отказывается делать и как будто зависает.

Подумалось, что это может быть связано с правами, т.е. нет у пользователя прав на такие операции.

В результате для `php.exe` для группы Users назначил все права (были только на чтение и исполнение), и в результате ВСЁ ЗАРАБОТАЛО!!!

Осталось непонятным только как такое могло произойти - админы вроде сам php и все что с ним связано не трогали. Интересно, они могли обновляя что-то в ОС сбросить права всяким php.exe и другим файлам?